# How to generate an [error] instead of an [info] upon seeing a wrong value in expect()

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, chisel

Consider the following code:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._
import chisel3.iotesters._

class Inverter extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Input(UInt(4.W))
    val s = Output(UInt(4.W))
  })
  io.s := ~io.a
}

class InverterTester(c: Inverter) extends PeekPokeTester(c) {
  poke(c.io.a, 8)
  step(1)
  expect(c.io.s, 8) // Should be 7 here
}

object TestMain extends App {
  chisel3.iotesters.Driver.execute(args, () => new Inverter()) {
    c => new InverterTester(c)
  }
}
```

Now I run `sbt 'test:runMain TestMain'` and got this line (`info` is in purple):

```
[info] [0.002] EXPECT AT 1   io_s got 7 expected 8 FAIL
```

And the exit value of `sbt` is zero.

I need that line to be an error (with red color):

```
[error] [0.002] EXPECT AT 1   io_s got 7 expected 8 FAIL
```

As well as making the above `sbt` command exit with a non-zero value.

How can I achieve it with minimal change to existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the easy part. You can get a non-zero result code by using the result of chisel.execute like this.

```
  val result = chisel3.iotesters.Driver.execute(args, () => new Inverter()) {
    c => new InverterTester(c)
  }
  System.exit(if(result) 0 else 1)
```

Changing the logging level, unfortunately requires changing each of the separate backends in the chisel-testers repo. The following is an example of changing the *TreadleBackend.scala*, one of the three.

```
  def expect(signal: InstanceId, expected: BigInt, msg: => String)
    (implicit logger: TestErrorLog, verbose: Boolean, base: Int) : Boolean = {
    signal match {
      case port: Element =>
        val name = portNames(port)
        val got = treadleTester.peek(name)
        val good = got == expected

        if (!good) {
          logger error
                  s"""EXPECT AT $stepNumber $msg  $name got ${bigIntToStr(got, base)} expected ${bigIntToStr(expected, base)}""" +
                          s""" ${if (good) "PASS" else "FAIL"}"""
        }
        else if (verbose) {
          logger info
                  s"""EXPECT AT $stepNumber $msg  $name got ${bigIntToStr(got, base)} expected ${bigIntToStr(expected, base)}""" +
                          s""" ${if (good) "PASS" else "FAIL"}"""
        }
        if(good) treadleTester.expectationsMet += 1
        good
      case _ => false
    }
  }
```

This would not be an unreasonable issue to file, I think a logger.error would make more sense on an *expect* failure.  There is some concern that changing this could have unexpected consequences for existing users, who are looking for that string.

But I'd like to encourage you to take a look at [freechipsproject/chisel-testers2](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2) repo. It's where the team is putting most of their testing development time. It would be easier to change, it has a lot of other nice features for building unit tests, and we are looking at ways we can make it better than *chisel-testers*.